# TypeScript Error - TS7016 - (TS) Could not find a declaration file for module 'redux-localstorage'

Tags: typescript

I have upgraded my environment to TypeScript 2.4.1 and have turned `"strict": true,` in my tsconfig.json. I really love the strict null checking, it's soooo cool but, I’m running into a brick wall with the redux stuff I’m using.  What I’m using is the module ‘redux-localstorage’ installed through npm.  It’s old and probably out of date for this new TypeScript compiler and was working with no issues.  It is throwing an error, “TS7016 - (TS) Could not find a declaration file for module 'redux-localstorage'.”

I found a ‘@types/ redux-localstorage’ for it but, it seems, was done to a much older version of the module with different parameters than I have.  As I stated, I know the module works, it’s just not working with this strict type checks.

The thing is, I’m calling the module from just one .ts file and, I am only using one function. So, at the top of this .ts file I have this import statement:

`import persistState from 'redux-localstorage';`

This statement worked fine before I updated to the newer TypeScript and turned on strict checking but, now I get the stated error.

I have two questions does anyone know a quick and easy fix? I don’t really want to turn off the strict checking (I assume that is what is causing the issue).  But maybe there is a way to turn it off for just this file?

Second question is, if there is no “quick fix” can I just write my own ‘.d.ts’ file for this module, really just this one function.  If so can anyone give me pointers as to how?  As stated, I only need to create a type for the one function.

**Update - I have solved the problem**

I created this type file:

```
// Type definitions for redux-localstorage persistState, until a better solution becomes available
import * as Redux from "redux";

export interface ConfigRS {
    key: string;
    merge?: any;
    slicer?: any;
    serialize: (value: any, replacer?: (key: string, value: any) => any, space?: string | number) => string,
    deserialize: (text: string, reviver?: (key: any, value: any) => any) => any
}

export default function persistState(paths: string | string[], config: ConfigRS): Redux.GenericStoreEnhancer;
```

I then had to add this file as the filename index.d.ts to the `node_modules/@types/redux-localstorage` directory

Thanks for the suggestions....

Comment: Thanks for the link reference but, I think I need a type that describes the function and parameters and return type from the function

Comment: normally I'm not one of those RTFM people, but what is preventing you from reading the documentation and doing it?

Comment: Well, nothing I guess, I was looking for some sample code or guidance on how to accomplish this task.  I have been able to create a '.d.ts' file for it and it works!  I'll edit the question with my solution